Analysing a Lebesgue integral inequality for $|t^{-n} \phi(x/t)|$, where $\phi \in C_c^\infty \cap L^1$ with $\| \phi \|_1 = 1$.
Context. Let $C^k(\mathbb R^n)$ denote the space of functions defined on $\mathbb R^n$ that are $k$ times continuously differentiable, where $k \geqslant 1$ is an integer. As usual, define $C^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ to be the intersection of all $C^k(\mathbb R^n)$ and let $C_c(\mathbb R^n)$ denote the space of continuous functions on $\mathbb R^n$ with compact support. Furthermore, let $C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^n) = C_c(\mathbb R^n) \cap C^\infty(\mathbb R^n).$
Consider the usual Euclidean space $\mathbb R^n$ equipped with the Lebesgue measure. Furthermore, let $\phi \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ be a kernel with unitary norm, that is, $\| \phi \|_1 = 1$ (here, $\| \phi \|_1$ stands for the $L^1$-norm of $\phi$) and define the dillations
$$ \phi_t(x) = t^{-n} \phi\left( \frac{x}{t} \right), $$
for every $x \in \mathbb R^n$ and $t > 0$. Finally, let $\delta > 0$ be an arbitrary fixed constant. In an article I am reading, the authors claim the following.

Now, we use the very well-known inequality
$$ \int_{|z| \geqslant \delta}|\phi_t(z)| \, dz \leqslant c \, \int_{|z| \geqslant \delta} \frac{t}{|z|^{n+1}} \, dz \leqslant c \, t, $$
where the constant $c$ is independet of $t$.

Basically, I am wondering where this inequality comes from and if anyone has a reference that approaches this result.
For what it's worth, under these conditions I am already aware that $\phi_t \in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ with $\| \phi_t \|_1 = 1$ (for details about this, see this post).
Thanks for any help in advance.

Surely $C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^n) \subset L^1(\mathbb R^n)$? What does the subsript $c$ mean here?

@copper.hat The subscript $c$ stands for compact support. So, $C^\infty_c (\mathbb R^n)$ stands for the usual class of infinitely differentiable functions with compact support on $\mathbb R^n$. You are correct on the inclusion you provided, so that I could simplify the notation on my post. Does that inclusion helps on the deducing the inequality ? (I will add more context about the meaning of $C_c^\infty$ to the post in order to remove any confusion).

@copper.hat I've edited the post according to your comment (notation simplified + context on the meaning of $C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$.

Do I understand this correctly that the constant $c$ is allowed to depend on $\phi$? Also is there a $t$ missing somewhere in the well-known inequality (the expression in the middle has no $t$ at all).

@SeverinSchraven You are correct that there is a $t$ missing. Thanks for your comment (I've edited the post accordingly). Yes, you understand correctly that the constant $c$ might depend on $\phi$. The only important thing to the conclusions presented in the article is that the constant is independent of $t$.

The essential ingredients are that $\phi\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and that $\phi$ has compact support (no need to assume any regularity or boundedness).
The compact support condition is telling us that there exists $R>0$ such that $\phi(z)=0$ for $\vert z \vert \geq R$. Thus, for $t\leq \delta/R$, we get
$$ \int_{\vert z \vert\geq \delta} \vert \phi_t(z)\vert dz =
\int_{\vert w \vert \geq \delta/t} \vert \phi(w) \vert dw =0. $$
On the other hand, for $t>\delta/R$ we have
$$ \int_{\vert z \vert\geq \delta} \vert \phi_t(z)\vert dz  \leq \Vert \phi_t\Vert_1 =1 \leq (\delta/R)^{-1} t. $$
Thus, in total, we have for all $t>0$
$$ \int_{\vert z \vert\geq \delta} \vert \phi_t(z)\vert dz \leq (\delta/R)^{-1} t. $$
Added: We have
$$\int_{\vert z\vert\geq \delta} \vert \phi_t(z)\vert dz=\int_{\vert z\vert\geq \delta} t\vert z/t\vert^{n+1} \vert \phi(z/t)\vert/\vert z\vert^{n+1} dz \leq \left(\sup_{y\in \mathbb{R}^n} \vert y\vert^{n+1} \vert\phi (y) \vert \right) \int_{\vert z\vert\geq \delta} \frac{t}{\vert z\vert^{n+1}} dz.$$
This is probably what the authors had in mind.
The nice thing here is that it is enough to have $\phi\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and
$$\sup_{y\in \mathbb{R}^n} \vert y\vert^{n+1} \vert \phi(y)\vert <\infty.$$
In particular, compact support can be replaced with sufficiently fast decay at infinity (though we need boundedness around zero now).

On your second "paragraph", shouldn't it be $t \leqslant R/\delta$ or am I missing something ?

@xyz Note that $t\leq \delta/R$ is equivalent to $R\leq \delta/t$. Thus, if $\vert w \vert \geq \delta/t \geq R$ we get $\vert \phi(w)\vert =0$, which is what we want.

Yes, of course, sorry. This is a very good answer. Do you think there is any particular reason for the authors to present the middle step? In other words, in your answer there is nothing similar to $$ \int_{|z| \geqslant \delta} \frac{t}{|z|^{n+1}} , dz $$ and the authors have this middle step. Am I missing something or did you approach this in a slightly different way ?

@xyz I must admit that I have no idea what this middle step is meant to indicate.

@xyz I think I know now what they had in mind. See my edit.

This is very good, I have to admit. If I remember, I will take the time to create a bounty on this question and award it to you. Thanks for your help.

@xyz Thanks for the kind words. I must say that I like those type of riddles as it involves only basic calculus and yet they can be somewhat challenging :)

@xyz Thank you very much for the bounty!

Since $\phi \in C_{c}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, there is $R > 0$ such that $\phi(x) = 0$ if $|x| \geq R$, so $\phi_t(z) = 0$ if $|z| \geq tR$, now, using the change of coordinates $z = ty$ you have
$$
\int_{|z| \geq \delta} |\phi_t(z)| \ dz = \int_{tR \geq |z| \geq \delta} |\phi_t(z)| \ dz \leq t^{-n}\int_{R\geq |y| \geq t^{-1}\delta} |\phi(y)| t^{n} \ dy = \int_{R\geq |y| \geq t^{-1}\delta} |\phi(y)| \ dy.
$$
Notice that this integral is $0$ if $t^{-1}\delta > R$ (i.e. $t < R^{-1}\delta$) and therefore the bound in this case is trivial, otherwise, using spherical coordinates:
\begin{align*}
\int_{|z| \geq \delta} |\phi_t(z)| \ dz &\leq \lVert \phi \rVert_{\infty}\int_{R\geq |y| \geq t^{-1}\delta}  \ dy = \lVert \phi \rVert_{\infty}\int_{t^{-1}\delta}^{R}\int_{\mathbb{S}^{n-1}} r^{n-1} \ d\omega \ dr \\ 
&=\lVert \phi \rVert_{\infty}n\omega_{n}\int_{t^{-1}\delta}^{R}r^{n-1} \ dr 
=\lVert \phi \rVert_{\infty}\omega_{n}\left(R^{n} - t^{-n}\delta^{n}\right) \\ 
&=\lVert \phi \rVert_{\infty}\omega_{n}\frac{(R^{n}t^{n}-\delta^{n})}{t^{n+1}}t \leq ct.
\end{align*}
The bound in the end is due to the fact that the function defined in $[R^{-1}\delta,+\infty)$ as
$$
x \mapsto \lVert \phi \rVert_{\infty}\omega_{n}\frac{(R^{n}x^{n}-\delta^{n})}{x^{n+1}}
$$
is bounded, since it is continuous and
$$
\lim_{x \to +\infty}\lVert \phi \rVert_{\infty}\omega_{n}\frac{(R^{n}x^{n}-\delta^{n})}{x^{n+1}} = 0.
$$

Nice answer! I am sorry, I did not see your answer while typing.

This is a very good answer, too. There is the same "flaw" (which really isn't a flaw, but I  find no other way to describe it) as in the answer from Severin, since there seems to be no sign of the middle step. Either way, this is obviously good enough to answer my question (+1). Unfortunately I can't accept two answers and Severin's one seems more elegant to me.
